# Vue 3 ::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use ::v-deep(<inner-selector>) instead

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

I started getting the following warning in Vue 3 with the `::v-deep` usage.

> `::v-deep` usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use
> `::v-deep(<inner-selector>)` instead

The CSS looks like as follows:

```
.parent ::v-deep .child {
   ...
}
```

What's the correct way to use suggested option `::v-deep(<inner-selector>)`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The relevant RFC is here:

https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0023-scoped-styles-changes.md

I believe you need to change it to:

```css
.parent ::v-deep(.child) {
```

**Update:**

The warning message mentioned in the question has been changed in later versions of Vue 3 to recommend using `:deep()` instead. This is an alias for `::v-deep()` and it has been added to the documentation here:

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#deep-selectors

Comment: what if there is a object behind ::v-deep? how to tansfter it to :deep() format ?
for example:
::v-deep {
.sortable-ghost {
opacity: .8;
color: #fff !important;
}

.el-tag {
cursor: pointer;
}
}

Comment: use space hack

:deep( ) {
  .sortable-ghost {
    opacity: .8;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  .el-tag {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

Answer (score 76):

Little update: now, you need to change it to:

```
.parent :deep(.child) {
    (CSS rules)
}
```

Comment: I want to note after wasting 30 minutes that the way this works is :deep(.child){ css rules here }, it was not obvious the {} part and css rules, especially coming from the old way of doing it.  Hope this helps someone.  Please update your example if you don't mind to add more information

Answer (score 15):

This issue also occurs in Vue 2.7

```
[@vue/compiler-sfc] ::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use :deep(<inner-selector>) instead.
```

I I think neither of the solutions above solve that warning.

Edited working using:

```
:deep() {
  .class {}
}
```

But it finds error in npm dependencies as well

Comment: I randomly started getting this error in a nuxt 2.15.7 application a couple of weeks ago and I have no idea what to do about it. I'd try your solution, but I'm kinda discouraged to try it with with how many v-deeps I'd have to update and it still firing coz of dependencies.

Comment: @SeriousLee Try to roll back vue to 2.6 version ;)

Answer (score 2):

Vue3

[image: div]

```css
div:deep(.v-img) {
    overflow: visible;
}
```